# Who's the manufacturer and what year was this tandem bike manufactured?

Tags: identify-this-bike, tandems

The previous owner said this could possibly be a Schwinn:
[image]

Comment: Greetings, and welcome to bicycles.SE.  We recommend that all new users take [the tour](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/tour) to get the most from the site.  If your tandem has a head badge, a picture would probably help.  Is there a serial number on the underneath of one of the bottom brackets?

Comment: It could be a Schwinn.  Is the kickstand welded on?  What brand is stamped on the arm of the rear brake?  (I'm thinking that Schwinn used Bendix pretty much exclusively, and few other manufacturers did.)

Comment: That's going to be a terribly flexy frame to ride, given the rhombus between the seat tubes.  Triangles for the win!

Comment: @Criggie there's enough triangles, it's lateral flex and cheap, bendy tubing that's going to hurt. There will be no standing up and pedalling. Well, maybe once...

Comment: I would have expected the parallelogram (not a rhombus, sorry) between front saddle and rear bottom bracket to flex vertically, ie two pair of scissors movements.

Comment: Bendix 70 stamped on the brake, and yes the kickstand is welded... but couldn't find SR# anywhere, no head badge either, but two small holes to hold a head badge are there...

Answer (score 8):

It's a Schwinn Twinn. The serial number will be located on one of the rear dropouts, if it's not on either side of the head tube. There are a couple websites that will help you determine the date of manufacture. Judging from the type of tires fitted to the rim, and the shape of the rim, I surmise that the bike has had both wheels replaced at some point, as the bike no longer has S-7 rims and tires, which would have been stock on a Schwinn.

Comment: Good answer - thank you for your contribution to the site.  Please keep it up.